# How to store a MySQL value in a web page for later use

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am fetching just one cell value from a MySQL table with php and storing it in a div with an id.
I am then trying to use that div later on in JavaScript code.

I think the php/MySQL code is all correct but there is a problem using the div value in the later JavaScript code.

What is the best way to store a MySQL value in a web page for later use?

Currently I am storing the returned result as:

```
<div id="IsShift04Special"></div>
```

Using:

```
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("IsShift04Special").innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
    }
};
```

It all seemingly works well.

If I double click the 1 on the page in a browser and paste it into notepad it pastes just the 1.
There are no visible carriage returns or spaces anywhere near it.

But when I try to use the 1 value later on with:

```
var IsItASpecial = document.getElementById("IsShift04Special").innerHTML;
```

Then use that in an if statement, it is not working.

When I check the value of IsItASpecial (where it is declared and in the if statement), in the Chrome debugger it returns as:

```
IsItASpecial = "↵↵↵↵↵     1 ↵↵↵"
```

The table currently has just one row.

The value is tinyint(1) with a value of 1.

This is the php query:

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT shift04_special FROM `shifts` WHERE `users_username`= '$users_username' AND `companies_short_name` = '$companies_short_name' AND `job_role_short_name` = '$job_role_short_name'");  

$special_shift04 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $special_shift04['shift04_special'];
```

I get the same problem with:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo 'shift04_special';
}
```

And:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["shift04_special"];
}
```

When I do a var dump as:

```
var_dump($special_shift04);
```

This part is returned:

```
["shift04_special"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

So it seems the problem is with my code for returning the div value and then storing it in a var.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be consistent. If the column is of type `tinyint`, `vardump` should not be putting `string(1) "1"`. Is the column a numeric type, or a string type?

Comment: double-checked: shift04_special tinyint(1)  - (copy and paste from phpMyAdmin)

Comment: If you want something for future use, relying on JS alone isn't a good idea. You want serverside (also).

Comment: Serverside? So use php (or something else) to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typical typecast problem. MySQL storing data separately from PHP. So types in MySQL != types in PHP. Because of it you did  string(1) "1" in your PHP var_dump() function.

So in your case, when you getting a value in Javascript environment you should cast this value to type that you need.  In your case like this:

```
var IsItASpecial = parseInt(document.getElementById("IsShift04Special").innerHTML);
```

But. I don't recommend use JS like that in production. But for learning it's OK!

Have fun

Comment: Thank you very much. That has sorted it nicely.

Comment: This prompted me to look into it further and I found just by putting a + sign in front of the document.getElementById part also changed it into an integer.  Is this ok to use too?

Answer (score 1):

You can save it directly in a JavaScript variable.

```
var id=<?php echo $row['shift04_special'] ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try to store in localstorage in a JSON format,

`// Fetch from server
localStorage.setItem("mysqlResponse", JSON.stringify(response));`

Now whenever you need the value,

`const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("mysqlResponse"));`